# Preg Match That Allows Spaces, Dashes, And Normal Characters

Tags: php, regex

I am extremely sorry for asking this! There is so many resources for `Regex` but I am simply terrible at using it and understanding the documentation.

This is a bit urgent.

I own a site where users can upload files. Recenlty, a user started uploading tons of files that have a name similar to this:

```
1538æŽä»£æ²«&æ›²å©‰å©·å¯¹å”±ã€Šæˆ‘çš„æ­Œå£°é‡Œã€‹è¿½å¿†ç½—çº³å°”å¤š.flv
```

He is doing some really funky stuff.

I have been trying to build a regex that would work properly and stop users from uploading files with weird names. I found this from another question:

```
function isValid($str) {
return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.#\\-$]/', $str);
}
```

The problem is, this is a bit too strict. It does not allow spaces.

I need to edit the function to allow `spaces`, `dashes`, `$ signs`, and `single quotes`. But not much more than that.

How can I do this?

Thanks so much for any help! I apologize for my terrible regex knowledge.

Comment: If I may ask: What hinders you to add spaces and dollar signs as well as single quotes to the pattern? Also these "weird" names might be just some UTF-8 encoded name in some non-english language. You might want to check the encoding chain of the input.

Comment: As it turns out, you are right. The language is not English and they are actually normal files. They should look something like this: 第七期《 中国好声音 How can I fix the encoding?

Comment: what do you want to support for file-names? Do you need to have these file-names on disk actually or only inside the database? Which encoding does your file-system support? And which encoding does your website use. And which encoding does your database use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the single quotes to a string (any string) in PHP you need to "escape" it by adding a slash in front:

```
'\''
 ^- slash
```

That is needed because otherwise PHP would not understand from where to where the string definition goes.

The `$` and `-` signs have a special meaning inside the character class in a regular expression, so they need some kind of escape as well. That is again with a `\` slash, however to write a slash inside a PHP single quoted string it needs another slash as well:

```
'\\'
```

So to build the regex all this needs to be brought together (and if you move the dash to the end of the character class it has no special meaning):

```
'/[^A-Za-z0-9.# \\$\'-]/'
               ^ ^ ^- slash for the single quote
               | `- slashed slash for the $ sign
               `- space
```

I have not tested this, but as you may see, it can get a bit complicated because first there is some escaping for the PHP string and then there is some escaping for the regular expression pattern.